# Finding closest marker to my location with gmaps.js

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I'm using gmaps.js and I created a couple of markers on the map, then I used geolocation to find my location on the map, so far so good, the only problem I have now is for it to find the closest marker to me and then maybe also draw a path line from where I am to that marker

The code I have so far:

```
var map;
map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map_canvas',
    lat: 36.111114,
    lng: -104.88118,
    zoom: 16,
    zoomControl: 0,
    streetViewControl: 0,
    mapTypeControl: 0,
    panControl: 0
});
map.addMarker({
    lat: 36.072967,
    lng: -105.007866,
    title: 'Marker 1'
});
map.addMarker({
    lat: 36.072967,
    lng: -105.007866,
    title: 'Marker 2'
});
map.addMarker({
    lat: 36.160746,
    lng: -104.908646,
    title: 'Marker 3'
});
GMaps.geolocate({
    success: function(position) {
        map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.addMarker({
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
            title: 'Your Location'
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('Geolocation failed: '+error.message);
    },
    not_supported: function() {
        alert("Sorry, your device does not support geolocation.");
    },
    always: function() {
        alert("Done!");
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well to be honest I just have no idea how to proceed and the demos on the site doesnt really do anything along those lines..

Answer (score 0):

You must compute distance between every marker and your location and pick up the point with the lowest distance. Take a look at [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). There is a description of a method which computes the distance between two latlng points with example code in JS. That should be enough to solve your problem